# Evaluate $\int \arcsin \left(\sqrt{x}\right)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Evaluate:
> $$\int \arcsin \left(\sqrt{x}\right)dx$$

I am really stuck here. I know that I have to use $u-$substitution and set $u = \sqrt{x}$, to get $\left(2\int \arcsin \left(u\right)\cdot \:udu \right)$ but how can I continue from here? Could I use integration by parts and use $u = \arcsin(u), v'=u$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use integration by parts:\begin{align}\int\arcsin(u)u\,\mathrm du&=\frac12\arcsin(u)u^2-\frac12\int\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du\\&=\frac12\arcsin(u)u^2-\frac12\left(\int\frac{u^2-1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du+\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du\right)\\&=\frac12\arcsin(u)u^2+\frac12\int\sqrt{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du-\frac12\arcsin(u).\end{align}And now you can compute $\int\sqrt{1-u^2}\,\mathrm du$ doing $u=\sin(\theta)$ and $\mathrm du=\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$.

Answer (score 8):

Substitute $y=\arcsin\sqrt x$. Then, $dx= \sin 2y \>dy$ and
$$\int \arcsin \sqrt{x}\>dx
=\int y \sin 2y \>dy \overset {IBP}= -\frac12 y \cos 2y +\frac14\sin2y+C
$$